# What's the exact buffered time when MediaPlayerElement can really play?

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement` to play online videos. We all know `MediaPlayerElement` will buffer a little time of the video and then to play the video.

For `ios`, if the video is 1 hour, they only buffer 2s of the video, and can play it. (after played 2s, the player will continue to buffer).

But how long is the buffer time on uwp? I can't find any official docs.

Comment: I tried on a slow network, it seems MediaPlayerElement' buffer time is 4s. But still no official doc.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that we don't have more information to share with you because it is not explained in the documentation. For now, we can't directly set the buffer duration of `MediaPlayerElement`.

Comment: OK, it seems MediaPlayerElement has a long way to go.